# Magento 2: addFieldToFilter check for NULL not working

Tags: magento2, database

I am trying to get the records from database which contains `parent_item_id` **NULL** value.

```
$order_ = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Saleslist')
                    ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                'order_id',
                $orderId
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'parent_item_id',
                ['eq' => NULL]
            );
```

and also want to add the `parent_item_id` equal **NULL** or  **' '** string check.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try with, `array('null' => true)`

```
 $order_ = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Saleslist')
                        ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter(
                    'order_id',
                    $orderId
                )->addFieldToFilter(
                    'parent_item_id',
                    array('null' => true)
                );
```

Comment: one more question i want to add or clause for the `parent_item_id`

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320690/magento-combine-eq-and-is-null-in-addattributetofilter

Comment: Have you work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug until Magento 2.3, that prevents to filter a collection by "null" attribute value.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14355

In my case, updating to Magento 2.3 fixed the problem.